# While using python manage.py migrate command in powershell , I got the following error message

Tags: python, django, pip

[Screenshot of powershell admin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYE6T.png)

Can you please help me fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: I've tried that but still it shows the same error. Can you please point out my mistakes , I'm new to this so I'm unable to figure this out.

Comment: try this one It might be useful.        first of all, drop the database, and create a new one and delete all the migrations files except init.py, then follow the steps

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of the picture, it says the `SECRET_KEY` setting is empty.

Try adding the following line to your `settings.py`:

```
SECRET_KEY = '<INSERT SECRET STRING HERE>'
```

Comment: Yes sir , I've done that , but it still shows the exact same message. Is it possible that the error is arising from cached data?

Comment: I doubt it's a caching issue. in your manage.py file, are you referencing the correct settings.py as the root of your project?

What happens if you run `python manage.py shell` and run `from django.conf import settings; print(settings.SECRET_KEY)`